# Loading SKLearn cancer dataset into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to load a sklearn.dataset, and missing a column, according to the keys (target_names, target & DESCR). I have tried various methods to include the last column, but with errors.

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

 cancer = load_breast_cancer()
 print cancer.keys()
```

> the keys are ['target_names', 'data', 'target', 'DESCR', 'feature_names']

```
 data = pd.DataFrame(cancer.data, columns=[cancer.feature_names])
 print data.describe()
```

with the code above, it only returns 30 column, when I need 31 columns. What is the best way load scikit-learn datasets into pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Can you explain why there should be 31 columns? If you use `cancer.data.shape` or check [the dataset description](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer.html), it seems that there are only 30 columns in the dataset. Which column have you missed?

Comment: I'm missing the target/target_names column from the dataset.keys(), as it hasn't been loaded into data frame yet.

Answer (score 17):

Another option, but a one-liner, to create the dataframe including the features and target variables is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

cancer = load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[cancer['data'], cancer['target']],
                  columns= np.append(cancer['feature_names'], ['target']))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have a `target` column you will need to add it because it's not in `cancer.data`. `cancer.target` has the column with `0` or `1`, and `cancer.target_names` has the label. I hope the following is what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

cancer = load_breast_cancer()
print cancer.keys()

data = pd.DataFrame(cancer.data, columns=[cancer.feature_names])
print data.describe()

data = data.assign(target=pd.Series(cancer.target))
print data.describe()

# In case you want labels instead of numbers.
data.replace(to_replace={'target': {0: cancer.target_names[0]}}, inplace=True)
data.replace(to_replace={'target': {1: cancer.target_names[1]}}, inplace=True)
print data.shape # data.describe() won't show the "target" column here because I converted its value to string.
```

Comment: Yes, I just figured out, data['Target'] = pd.Series(data=cancer.target, index=data.index) works too.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This works too, also using pd.Series.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

cancer = load_breast_cancer()
print cancer.keys()

data = pd.DataFrame(cancer.data, columns=[cancer.feature_names])
data['Target'] = pd.Series(data=cancer.target, index=data.index)

print data.keys()
print data.shape
```

Answer (score 1):

Only target column is missing, so you can just add one.

```
df =  pd.DataFrame(cancer.data, columns=[cancer.feature_names])
df['target'] = cancer.target
```

Answer (score 0):

mapping target names can be handled elegantly using *map()*:

```
data["target"] = pd.Categorical(pd.Series(cancer.target).map(lambda x: cancer.target_names[x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As of scikit-learn 0.23 you can do the following to get a DataFrame with the target column included.

```
df = load_breast_cancer(as_frame=True)
df.frame
```